# Python: condições para vários símbolos

Tags: python

Estou com uma duvida, lembro de já ter visto em algum lugar a resolução porem não estou encontrando mais. Então o problema tenho vários símbolos por exemplo `simbolos = ('!','?',',','\'')` aqui ele está como tupla que é como imaginei que funcionária, mas não. Quero fazer verificação de todos em um `if` desta forma mais ou menos: `if (simbolos in palavra):`.

Comment: Você precisa verificar se todos os símbolos estão na palavra?

Comment: Preciso que ele verifique se dos `simbolos`, possui algum dentro da palavra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você precisa verificar se pelo menos um operadores está na palavra, você pode utilizar a função `any`:

```
if any(simbolo in palavra for simbolo in simbolos):
    print('Pelo menos um símbolo está na palavra')
```

Ou você pode utilizar conjuntos e verificar se há intersecção:

```
simbolos = set(('!', '?', ',', '\''))
palavra = set('Pergunta?')

if simbolos & palavra:
    print('Pelo menos um símbolo está na palavra')
```

Comment: Exato, valeu a força

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um exemplo simples, não se pode comparar uma lista inteira com uma string, então para facilitar usei função lambda que irá percorrer a lista dos simbolos e checar um a um se a string especial se encontra na frase.

```
simb = ['!','?',',','\\']
frase = 'Somente hoje, eu cheguei mais cedo!'

if lambda x: simb in frase:
    print True
else:
    print False
```

Repare também que eu mudei o '\'' para '\', pois pois é assim que o python reconhece o "\" como string. A saída do código será:

```
Output: True
```

Comment: É uma boa solução, mas no meu caso estou usando para retirar alguns espaços em branco e fiz um split na frase para pegar as palavras.